# How to get logo img to extend beyond/outside of header

Tags: css

I'm trying to get this logo image to extend outside of the header so that it dips into the content when you scroll. It's essentially look like the logo is too big for the header and is hanging off the bottom.

Here's the website: http://185.56.86.90/~onetoncr/test3.com/

Here's an example where the logo (green square) extends past the header: http://185.56.86.90/~onetoncr/friedmanpr.com.

They both use Bodega theme in wordpress and the only difference is that the green FMPR is a different menu/header setting which means the header is in a div class called container and container_inner as well as all the other divs in the red One Ton site.

Tried adjusting the height and putting in z-indexes but it seems like it is contained in the header container. Is there a way to extend the logo outside of the header parent.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: i'm afraid you'll have to redo the navbar make it `position:relative` and the logo `position:absolute` and align it as you like

Answer (score 0):

Add in your css

```
.header_inner_left{
top: 2em !important;
background: #fff;
}
```

and remove `width:150px !important` in `.header_inner_left` from your custom.css, well its upto you though.

Comment: Great this seemed to have worked. I want to make the logo image bigger though and fill up the top space that's currently there now. How should I go about doing that? http://185.56.86.90/~onetoncr/test3.com/

Comment: as for size `.q_logo a{ height: 150px }` & `.logo_wrapper{width:200px}` you can change this width as per your requirements.

Comment: Great that works! Thanks! Now I'm trying to stop the logo from getting cut off when the header goes into a sticky header like this: https://postimg.cc/d78TpdDq. Tried to increase the height on `.header.sticky .logo_wrapper` to 150px with no luck.

Comment: in your `.logo_wrapper` add `overflow: visible`, see if it works

Comment: i just checked your website and your `.logo_wrapper{ overflow: visible }` is getting over rided with a media query, you can either change it in the media_query or you can simply `.logo_wrapper{ overflow: visible !important }`, i'll suggest changing it media query  `.stick_with_left_right_menu .logo_wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
}`- this is your media query at responsive.min.css.

Comment: Thanks! I tried edited it in the responsive.min.css but it wasn't responding, so I put it in the custom css with the !important and then it worked. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the line height on your menu items are pushing your header to the full 150px. `nav.main_menu > ul > li > a` has a `line-height: 150px` if you change that to 100px and then set your `.header_bottom` to have a height of 100px you logo will then stick out.

Just some general recommendation. Your markup and selector rules are really heavy. 
`nav.main_menu > ul > li > a` could easily just be `.main_menu a` which would take your specificity from 5 to 2 making it much easier to override later.

As for that huge line-height, that's gonna make your items clickable above and under in all that white space. That may be what you are going for but just keep in that in mind, you may want to make the hover more obvious just to provide the user with some better feedback that they are over a "button"

You could also reduce a lot of your mark up and styles by using Flexbox to center your menu items and stick them on either end. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/